# I've made a lot of promises. Am I expected to keep *all* of them?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

I formed a tribe! Awesome! The saga of my glorious clan and its many HeroQuests will surely ring out for many years. When negotiating to form this tribe, I made many promises. Some of them, I know, were kept automatically, such as allowing a neighboring clan to build a tavern on my Tula. Others... I'm not so sure about. Most notably the promises I've made to honor various gods with annual sacrifices.

Do I need to manually perform these various rites annually, or is this handled automatically behind the scenes like other promises? If the former, is shrine/temple maintenance sufficient?

Comment: By the way, I wrote a scene specifically about tribal promises, which is in the latest iOS release. I am not sure if it made it into HeroCraft’s Android or Steam port yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all of the promises are handled behind the scenes. I have never had a clan leave because I didn't sacrifice to a god or have an altar to one.

Rather than requiring the promises to be fulfilled by the player, making too many promises is punished at two points.

The first point is the actual tribal moot.If you have made too many promises, particularly any conflicting promises, you will have trouble successfully forming a tribe. You already got past that part though.

The second point is promise related events. For example, there is an event where (iirc) your women destroy the tavern built on your tula, because they are tired of the men getting drunk. Then you have to deal with it by repaying the tribe and letting them rebuild, repaying but not letting them rebuild, doing nothing and risking them leaving, etc.

Comment: This is how I know the promise to build a tavern is kept automatically. I'm mainly curious because the impeachment dialog makes reference to 'failing to uphold the oaths of the tribe' when my King is being deposed for some reason. But I guess that's just flavortext.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn’t make sense to force you to spend your actions trying to remember to do tribal stuff. Most of them you don’t have any direct way of doing.

You do get to influence whether the tribe has queens, however.